# Icons in context menu on Windows 8 taskbar are displaced

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, icons, context-menu, right-click

When I right click a taskbar-icon in Windows 8, The "pin program" and "close window" icons are behaving as shown in the image below. How to make these icons behave like the other ones in the context-menu (Google Chrome for example)?

[image: Broken icons]

Comment: Do you have any idea when this started appearing? Do you have a restore point you can revert to to when it was working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be caused in Windows 8.1 by using a 3rd party Windows 8 theme or if the update [KB3072318](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/69379-taskbar-jump-list-has-distorted-icons-placing-2.html#post518146) is installed. If you use no old theme, remove the update.

Comment: Thanks! It's correct now, after uninstalling this update.